# TYPO3: How to write comments correctly in typoscript constants?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

My first thought was just take a hash # but text with hash in typoscript constants is not really ignored by TYPO3. This for example is not a ignored comment:

```
# cat=category/subcategory/a; type=string; label=example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use these:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Plugin Constants
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Comment ###
```

the line you gave is interpreted:

- category: the name of your extension
- subcategory: with a label of your liking
- /a : helps put the voices in order

normally you put these lines in the beginning:

```
# customcategory=your-extension=MyExtension
# customsubcategory=a-general=MyExtension: Main Settings
```

[TYPO3 - refference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/TypoScriptTemplates/TheConstantEditor/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Those comments are used for the Constant Editor that you can find in the Template Module of the TYPO3 backend.

[Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/TypoScriptTemplates/TheConstantEditor/Index.html)